# Jammy 22.04 new install with Kubuntu gets flickering screen

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, xorg, 22.04, flicker

I'm running a new install of Jammy (22.04) on Ubuntu with KDE installed, X11, and a NVIDIA 470 driver.  I've started noticing that some small parts of the screen start flickering with content from somewhere else, possibly after a suspend and wake.  They go away when I move the window on top of them.  Then today I woke from suspend and most of my screen was flickering rapidly, showing mirror image windows and then switching back to normal windows.  Had to log out and back in, which fixed the problem.  Has anyone else encountered this?  I wonder whether it has anything to do with my VirtualBox install, which gets flaky after a suspend.  I'm waiting for it to start again to check my system logs.